# Uploading only fresh entries of managed object context to sever data base in ios

Tags: mysql, core-data, ios5, nsmanagedobjectcontext

I have developed a application that using core data framework to store the data. and i have a table view to display that data and also i made a button in the table view that upload the content to MYSQl database server on click. Now my problem is while uploading the content to database in need only freshly inserted entries to be uploaded to server database but in my application both fresh as well as old entries are uploading into the database. So please any body give me an idea about how to upload only the newly inserted entries.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a boolean attribute "uploaded" to your entity and filter the fetched entities to be uploaded.

OR

Use a timestamp attribute in your entity and keep the timestamp of the last successful upload.

OR

Keep a separate list with record IDs that have been uploaded successfully and filter them out before uploading.

OR

Use your server implementation to ignore duplicate entries.

Comment: I agree with your server implementation suggestion. But my concern is after i upload the content to database that entries are no more needed in managed object context so i just can keep the context clean right?

Comment: Correct. You could always devise a scheme to retrieve needed records from the online source.